# The model backing database is out of date ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I get an error when I try publishing and going to my website. It says
[image]

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948205/model-backing-a-db-context-has-changed-consider-code-first-migrations

Comment: Did you consider using Code First Migrations?

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding             Database.SetInitializer<ForumContext>(null); but now I get another error saying invalid column name for 'Votes'.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error when your c# code model is not in sync with your database tables.

Doing an EF migration will help to align those two things since EF will generate a set of SQL scripts to transform your database model to match up with your c# entities.

Comment: Im not sure if you are using the Code First method for intereacting with EF. I was in the past, and I used this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx to help me learn what migrations are and how to do them. There are plenty of resources on the web to learn how to do this.

Comment: Looks like that link above is pretty old now...it now suggests you go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621