# Why is my custom DbContext creating a table on insert?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm working on an ASP MVC project.

Here are the steps I followed :

- I added entity framework in my project references
- I connected to my SQL SERVER database and then copied the associated connection string in `Web.config` using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642578/7885071). The connection is successful
- I created manually my own DbContex class. Below is its code :

  ```
  public class MyConxtext : DbContext
  {
      public MyConxtext() : base("name = MyConnString"){}

      public DbSet<user> user { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Now user here not only is the name of my table `user` in SQL server but also is the name of my model `user` in my ASP MVC.

My problem is that :
- when I wanted to persist (several item in a session) via `MyContext.SaveChanges()`, it has created another table in my database named `users` ... Notice the plural here `users`... So instead of working on the table `user`, it created another table called `users` and persited data on that table.

My context also is not able to read data from the `user` table. BUT as I said it processes everything is the schema of the connection string

How can I solve that problem ?

Not only that it has also created another table in my schema called `MigrationHistory` which contain data about my project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `OnModelCreating` method in your DbContext and add the following line

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

This should remove pluralization for naming

Comment: I have no idea why this helped me. But it seems to have solved the problem. I have deleted MigrationHistory according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/37488834/7885071 and added your line to override the method. Problem solved. If you have time please elaborate on what exactly happened and why you gave that solution. ANYWAY THANK YOU MATE

Comment: It seems you have automatic migration enabled and by default EF uses pluralized table names. This option switches off this pluralization so that your model matches your existing schema

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework by default pluralizes the table name when it generates it from the supplied entities.That means, if there is a class named **Student** as entity object and you declare a **DbSet <Student>** on your context (class inherited from **DbContext**), by default EF creates the table in a plural form of the entity name. This is a general concept as the table will contain several rows of that entity type, which refers it will be a collection of the entities, in our case it will make a table named **Students**.

If you want to remove this default convention (System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions), you can override the method named

> onModelCreating()

of **DbContext** class.

In your code you can do

```
public class MyConxtext : DbContext
{
    public MyConxtext() : base("name = MyConnString"){}

    public DbSet<user> user { get; set; }




    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
    {  
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove < PluralizingTableNameConvention > ();  
    } 


 }
```

This will stop pluralizing the table's name in your database and it will use the **user** table of your database as you mentioned.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you mate. Your explanation made me better understand the code. By the way, I stuck on another problem...could you take a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507903/why-is-my-microsoft-owin-security-authenticationmanager-signin-method-not-workin