# Why is my microsoft.owin.security.authenticationmanager Signin method not working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

I working on an ASP MVC login form.

I have pretty simple codes. A `Startup` class and an action trying to set the cookie. Below is my code :

**Startup** 
which is located in App_Start (there is also a reference to it in `<appSetting>` with `key="owin:AppStartup"`)

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/auth/login"),
        });
    }
}
```

**The action method that is suppose to authenticate the user is :**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(user model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "admin@admin.com"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "tom"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin")
        });

        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
        var authManager = ctx.Authentication;
        authManager.SignIn(identity);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View(model); 
}
```

But this does not get the identity authenticated as `@User.Authenticated` is false in my `_Layout.cshtml` when `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` and also the debbuger shows that `IsAuthenticated` property is false (in the controller `Login` action and in the `_Layout.cshtml`.

I have checked that IIS is enabled for Anonymous authentication using my windows administrative tools and also I have checked that Startup is set when the application starts...

I seems that `authManager.SignIn(identity)` is not doing its job.

How can we solve this ?

[debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgT6P.png)

ps : I do not even see the browser popup asking if I want to save the password (I popped only once during my tests even though the user was still not authenticated)

Answer (score 1):

SignIn persists the user for future requests (via cookies), it does not alter the current request. You can directly set HttpContext.User for the current request if you want.

I also recall that you need to set the ClaimsIdentity AuthenticationType to CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType (or whatever auth type you're using to identify your middleware). Otherwise the cookie auth middleware won't activate.