# MVC 5 Context has changed since the database was created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm following a tutorial on MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6 and Autofac using VS 2013.

I believe the approach is Code First.

I missed out a step when creating my Model/Entity and came to light after the database was created.

When i load the site i receive

> The model backing the 'MyDbContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database.

I looked at

[Model backing a DB Context has changed; Consider Code First Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948205/model-backing-a-db-context-has-changed-consider-code-first-migrations)

but database was not available in my *Global.asax* possibly because I'm using `AutoFac`. Came across another thread which suggested to use `Enable-Migrations`
but get the error

> No context type was found in the assembly 'Web'

Tried

```
update-database -verbose -force
```

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Web'.

I know I can delete the database to get it resolved but I prefer to learn whatever resolves this issue in this scenario in case if it occurred on a production app.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You may are trying to apply Migrations upon the wrong project, make sure that the selected project is the project where your context is defined.

Comment: Do you have more than one project in your demo solution?

Comment: I selected the correct project this time and ran the command, got a mild error. Ran Add-Migration, gave it a name and then ran Update-Database which resolved the issue.