# Code First Update Database Error 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I am using MVC 5 and EF 6 with Code First. I got this error every time I tried to log in:

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since
> the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to
> update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

This program is ok for 2 years in development until this strange error come this week. Normally after we change the model, we just simply `update-database` and everything ok. Today we try to do the same and no error returned :

> ```
> PM> update-database
> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
> No pending explicit migrations.
> Applying automatic migration: 202012212240459_AutomaticMigration.
> Running Seed method.
> PM>
> ```

We are using automated migration. But i just try to add migration manually and update-database again successfully but still returning same error.

We tried to remove the database and recreate again using `update-database` and a new database created, create a dummy account but still returning the same error. Tried following and checking some suggestions in other threads and still not get a good result. Deleting migration history solved the error but when we `update-database` for future update it will create a duplicate error, so this is not counted as a solution. I don't know what to debug anymore and what to check. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you added a new migration after changing the model and before updating database?

Comment: @RobWhite Hi, we are using automated migration. But I just tried to add-migration manually and run the update-database succesfully but still returning the error. I will add it in question

Comment: Have you come across this stackoverflow question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948205/model-backing-a-db-context-has-changed-consider-code-first-migrations/37488834 I don't know if you've got several projects in your solution using entity framework. Apparently having different versions can cause this issue

Comment: @RobWhite Yes, we done that every time doing major changes. When I said we tried to remove and recreate the database, I mean doing like in that thread said.

Comment: I wasn't referring the main answer but one further down the thread (I don't know how to link to specific answers). Do you have multiple projects using entity framwork?

Comment: @RobWhite Yes, We checked everything in that thread before. And no, this solution just have 1 project in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226265/discussion-between-rob-white-and-jun-rikson).

Answer (score 0):

I think;  you change your entity class,
1 - Check your entites
2 - Check your DbSet in Context class
4  Check you entity frame work version
3- remove last migration and re install

Comment: I'm sorry, but do you know what you are posted?